# How can I prevent Range.selectNode() selecting too much of the DOM when attempting to select a node injected with appendChild()?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm facing an issue with the combination of using `appendChild()` and `Range.selectNode()` in JavaScript.

When attempting to use a range to select the newly-appended `<textarea>` node, it selects too much of the DOM.  Copying and pasting the selection seems to just contain a space.

However, if I put the `<textarea>` node into the DOM from the start (i.e. don't add it with `appendChild()`) then it works perfectly well and I can copy and paste the selected text as expected.

Note that the CSS isn't really necessary here, but it highlights the fact that the selection contains more than just the `<textarea>` (or at least it does in Chrome).

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a class="hoverTrigger">Click to trigger textarea element with selected text</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.floating {
    position: absolute;
}
```

JavaScript/jQuery (run on DOM ready):

```
$(".hoverTrigger").click(createAndSelectStuff);

function createAndSelectStuff() {
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.className = "floating";
    textArea.value = "Some dynamic text to select";
    this.parentNode.appendChild(textArea);
    selectObjectText(textArea);
    return false;
}

function selectObjectText(container) {    
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(container);
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);    
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3gpenfu/).

This is what the resulting selection looks like in Chrome:

[image: Image showing selection of DOM outside of intended area]

How can I stop this happening, and just select the desired text?

Comment: When I try it in Firefox, nothing is selected anywhere after clicking.

Comment: @Pointy Interesting, I'll add a screenshot of what I get in Chrome.

Comment: I can see it in Chrome. I'm inclined to call that a bug. The `<textarea>` is a weird thing because it's only partially like a real container element.

Comment: In both browsers, behavior does not change if I set `.innerHTML` (instead of `.value`) to the text.

Comment: @Pointy The same thing happens with `<input type="text">` as well.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe Chrome is getting confused because the target element isn't really a container; however it's hard for me to accept that what it does is correct behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your call to `selectObjectText` with:

```
container.setSelectionRange(0, container.value.length);
```

The problem with `textarea` elements is that they do not hold their contents in DOM nodes. The text value is a property of the element. When you call `range.selectNode`, what happens is that the range is set so as to encompass the node you pass to the function and the children node of this node, but since a `textarea` does not store its text in children nodes, then you select only the `textarea`.

`setSelectionRange` works with the value of an input element so it does not suffer from this problem. You might want to check the compatibility matrix [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement.setSelectionRange) to check which browsers support it.